# How does Ionic lazy loading works without importing the page into main module

Tags: ionic3

I have gone through the lazy loading of pages concept by Ionic.
However, I could not find the reference of how it works without using the import.

As per what I understand about Webpack it creates dependency graph based on what is imported in file e.g. `import { MyModule } from '../my-module';`

But in case of IonicPage, we are just importing the individual Ionic Page into declaration array of IonicPageModule of that page but this module is not imported anywhere ( Not in the main.module or app.module).

Please let me know if you have an idea about how does Ionic find the page without its being imported into main module.